# How do I make a catchall route in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm creating a CMS module for ZF2 and I'd like it to not have to include "/page" or somesuch in the url. So, for example, the url for the imprint page would be http://www.yourdomain.com/imprint

How would you suggest doing this? I've considered the following approaches, but I haven't been able to get any of them working just how I want:

1. Have a catchall route that connects to my PageController and passes the url path as a parameter. The problem here is getting the catchall route to play nice with existing routes. And this also means that all pages that should be 404 errors will now be routed through the PageController, which then has to handle 404 pages if the page is not found in the database.

   or
2. Observe the event EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR and recover from it if the page exists in the db. I can catch the event, but I have no idea how to recover from it and trigger the PageController.

   or
3. Any time a cms page title is created, updated or deleted, rebuild a cache of all cms routes. This seems like a clean solution, but I'm not sure how to proceed other than to build the cache as a php config file in the config/autoload directory.

I'll be grateful for any ideas on how to accomplish this. Ideally, the solution will be able to handle a CMS-powered homepage (/) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i'd take a differnt approach.

Option 1 would certainly work but I would create a new type of Router (CmsRouter), we can then make a route which is priority over your other static routes.

This route can check the database for a list of known pages / slugs, or even better to use some smart caching to make lookup quicker.

I certainly wouldn't use method 2) as you are using an error condition when there's no error at all, I would avoid doing that.

Comment: Andrew, Thanks for your suggestions. I agree that option #2 is a bad idea, so I eliminated that one. I'll accept your answer and then add a description of how I combined options #1 and #3 to make this work pretty nicely.

Comment: By the way, my open source CMS module for ZF2 is here: https://github.com/nhebi/Cms

Answer (score 2):

I ended up combining options #1 and #3. I set up a catchall route in my module config file:

```
return array(
    // Relative to app root
    'routeCacheFile' => 'data/cache/cmsRoutes',
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'cmsPage' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'priority' => 100,
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/:pageRoute',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'pageRoute' => 'dynamically-populated-by-bootstrap'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'pages',
                        'action' => 'view'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        // ...
    );
```

The first config option is the cache file. More about that later. Note that the route is a segment route with just one element `:pageRoute`. Then there's a constraint for it that we'll fill in in Module.php like this:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    $config = include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';

    // Get the cms page routes from a cache file
    if (!empty($config['routeCacheFile'])) {
        $cachedRoutes = file_get_contents($config['routeCacheFile']);

        $config['router']['routes']['cmsPage']['options']
            ['constraints']['pageRoute'] = $cachedRoutes;
    }

    return $config;
}
```

Instead of just including and returning the config array, I get the routeCacheFile setting, grab the contents of the file, and then use them to replace that 'dynamically-populated-by-bootstrap' constraint. The cache file contains a simple pipe-deliniated list of all published routes (more on that below), like this: `about|staff|some/longer/route|terms-of-service` One nice thing about this is that we don't need to connect to the database just to route a request.

I won't bore you with the code for the last bit, but each time my PageController saves a page, it triggers a service class that looks up all published routes and writes them out to the cache file in the config.

What do you think of this approach? It doesn't disrupt any existing routes (I used the priority setting to set the order that routes are matched), it doesn't require a db lookup to route a request and it doesn't require any abuse of error conditions.  Downsides: There's a dependency on the filesystem, which makes this harder to unit test. Maybe I could use Zend\Cache instead. It looks like the segment route constraint uses a regular expression. That might be a bit of a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Hostname router to create a catchall:

```
'wildcard' => array(
    'type' => 'Hostname',
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'options' => array(
        'route' => ':subdomain.:domain.:tld',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'ModName\Controller',
            'controller'    => 'ModName',
            'action'        => 'index'
        ),
    ),
),
```

You'd probably want to combine this with a dispatch event capable of changing the action. To solve a similar problem I attached a `SharedListenerAggregateInterface` with the following:

```
public function attachShared(SharedEventManagerInterface $sharedManager)
{
    $this->listeners[] = $sharedManager->attach('ModName\Controller\ModNameController', MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'changeAction'), 10);
}

public function changeAction(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $event)
{
    if (/* criteria for action foo */) {
        $event->getRouteMatch()->setParam('action','foo');
    } else if (/* criteria for action bar */) {
        $event->getRouteMatch()->setParam('action','bar');
    }
}
```

Because this is an MvcEvent, you have access to the service manager so you could do pretty much anything including database calls to check if routes are valid.